# Validation Rule not running the whole formula

Tags: validation-rule, regular-expressions

A field(Example__c, Text 255 char) can have a value of alphanumeric(numbers and/or letters) type and character length
should ONLY be either:

1. 3 character value
2. 7 character value
3. 12 character value

I have written the below validation rule:

```
AND(
    NOT(
        REGEX(Example__c,"[A-Za-z0-9])
    ),
    OR(
        LEN(Example__c) <> 3,
        LEN(Example__c) <> 7,
        LEN(Example__c) <> 12
    )
)
```

However while testing I see that although it's checking the alphanumeric validation but it's not checking the length at all. All values are getting saved no matter what the length is. I am unable to find what mistake I have made in the formula, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct version of the validation rule in your question is :

```
AND(
    NOT(
        REGEX(Example__c, "[A-Za-z0-9]")
    ),
    OR(
        LEN(Example__c) <> 3,
        LEN(Example__c) <> 7,
        LEN(Example__c) <> 12
    )
)
```

Notice the `"` at the end of Regex and an extra `)` removed.

But I think for the requirement which is described , we need to have `OR` operator instead of outermost `AND`.
This is because error needs to be thrown if either the field does not match the regex or its length is not valid.
Also , the length check needs to be an `AND`.
Based on above logic , validation rule becomes :

```
OR(
    NOT(
        REGEX(Example__c, "[A-Za-z0-9]")
    ),
    AND(
        LEN(Example__c) <> 3,
        LEN(Example__c) <> 7,
        LEN(Example__c) <> 12
    )
)
```

Comment: Yep, this looks spot-on. Hope you don't mind my edit. For others: The general "rules" with validation rules are: 1) They describe when your data is _invalid_ (instead of describing when data is valid). 2) If you're comparing a single field against multiple values, you need to use `OR()` for equality and `AND()` for inequality (because a single field can only hold 1 value at a time, it cannot be both value1 AND value2 and vice-versa for an inequality check).

Comment: @DerekF : Thank you for the edit. I will take care of the formatting next time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Firstly can you explain why we are enclosing the LEN part inside AND()? Value inside a field can only be 3 char or 7 char or 12 char, so I think we need OR() right? Secondly I tried this rule but now it is not accepting any value irrespective of the length. @Rohit

Comment: @Hatake_Kakashi : 1. We need to add formula for error , So , if the length is anything other than 3 , 7 ,12 we need to throw error. Let's consider , we put OR in place of AND , If the field length is 3 ,we satisfy condition for 7 and error gets thrown which is incorrect.
2. Formula is not working since regex appears to be incorrect. If you remove regex condition , it works for the lengths. You need to correct the regex as per your exact requirement.

Comment: @Rohit - Can you please tell me my mistake in REGEX? Since you did not make any changes earlier I thought it was fine.

Comment: @Hatake_Kakashi :You can check regex here - https://regex101.com/ . This regex works for alphanumeric characters with non-blank strings : ^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$

Comment: @Rohit - Thanks, it's working now.

Comment: Welcome @Hatake_Kakashi : Looking forward for your contributions in stack exchange.